# Story point in jira for done sprint

Tags: jira-agile

I need to fill in the story point for done sprint , because i was recoded it in excel the our management wants to extract reports from jira

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

- Create a sprint in Jira, set the appropriate start date and end date (even if these are in the past)
- Create Jira stories or tasks for each requirement in your Excel spreadsheet
- Add a story point estimate to each story/task
- Add the stories/tasks to the sprint you created
- Mark the sprint as ended